# How to change a variable at function at Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Assume that I have this code (at Python):

```
a=1
b=2
c=3

def x(a,b,c):
    a=5
    b=6
    c=7

x(a,b,c)
print(a,b,c)
```

The output will be: 1 2 3

My question is:
There is a why to change the values of `a,b,c` at `x(a,b,c)` (**without** return)?

Thank you!

Comment: You could make them globals inside `x` (and not pass them as parameters).  There's no way to do this via parameters, as a parameter conveys only a value - there's absolutely no connection to the variable the value came from.

Comment: The scope of a,b,c is local to the function x. You cannot change the values of a,b,c in the global scope where you print the vaule.

Comment: You can use the **global** keyword. But, why do you want to do that? Use a class.

Comment: @PCIL the use of global is frowned upon. You should return new values and assign them to new variables if you need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the **global** keyword:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3

def x():
    global a, b, c
    a = 5
    b = 6
    c = 7

x()
print(a,b,c)
# -> 5 6 7
```

Using a **class**:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def x(self):
        self.a = 5
        self.b = 6
        self.c = 7


foo = Foo(1, 2, 3)
print(foo.a, foo.b, foo.c)
# -> 1 2 3

foo.x()
print(foo.a, foo.b, foo.c)
# -> 5 6 7
```

Comment: As i stated, the use of `global` works, but as a new Python Programmer you should try to avoid it as a default pattern.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use the **global** modifier inside of the function to make the variables refer to the ones outside the function; however, this can result in a "code smell".

So inside the function, place global before those assignments and that should fix your problem.

Comment: You can use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43551485/edit) link.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to convert it into a list, as follows:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
l = [a, b, c]

def x(list):
    list[:] = [5, 6, 7]

x(l)

a, b, c = l
print(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

**As a new Python Programmer, PLEASE AVOID the use of `global`.** Globals may be useful for things like configuration, but for the most part they can cause dangerous side effects if you start to use them as your default programming paradigm. I'd suggest you try a class pattern, or variable assignment pattern.

**Class Assignment**

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def update(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

foo = Foo(1,2,3)
foo.update(5,6,7)
print "a: %d, b: %d, c: %d" % (foo.a, foo.b, foo.c)
```

**Variable Assignment**

```
a=1
b=2
c=3

def x():
    a_prime = 5
    b_prime = 6
    c_prime = 7
    return a_prime, b_prime, c_prime
a, b, c = x()
print a, b, c
```

Comment: Don't worry, I used the class and it was very helpful!! Thank you!